# Datatable RowGrouping throwing an Exception

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am using datatable and initialized as below:

```
function getDataTableGroupCompany() {

if (dataTableGroupCompany == null) {

     dataTableGroupCompany = $('#dataTables-companyGroupFilter').DataTable({
         'sDom' : 'tp',
         "bDeferRender": true,
         "aoColumns": [
                       {"sClass": "col1" },
                       {"sClass": "col2-current" },
                       null,
                       null,
                       {"sClass": "Just" }
                     ],
                     "iDisplayLength" : 20
                     /* "fnCreatedRow" : function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) 
                     {
                       var s = $('td:eq(3)', nRow).text();
                       try
                       {
                           $('td:eq(4)', nRow).text(mapCompany[s]);
                       }
                       catch(err)
                       {
                           alert("Y");
                           $('td:eq(4)', nRow).text("0");
                       }

                    } */
        });

     //dataTableGroupCompany.rowGrouping({bExpandableGrouping: true,iGroupingColumnIndex:3,iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex:4, sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "desc",bHideGroupingOrderByColumn:false,fnGroupLabelFormat:function(label){ if(mapCompany[label]!=null) return label+" ("+mapCompany[label]+")"; else return label; }});
     dataTableGroupCompany.rowGrouping({bExpandableGrouping: true,iGroupingColumnIndex:3,iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex:4, sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "desc",fnGroupLabelFormat:function(label){ if(mapCompany[label]!=null) return label+" ("+mapCompany[label]+")"; else return label; }});
}

return dataTableGroupCompany;    
}

 // ...//
 dataTableGroupCompany = getDataTableGroupCompany();
```

Now when I am trying to sort my table again using sortToggle function

```
 function sortToggle()
 {
var SortButton = $('#sortButton');

if(sort==true)
    {
    sort=false;

   //1st Exception in This line

    dataTableGroupCompany.rowGrouping({bExpandableGrouping: true,iGroupingColumnIndex:3,iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex:4, sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "desc",fnGroupLabelFormat:function(label){ if(mapCompany[label]!=null) return label+" ("+mapCompany[label]+")"; else return label; }});

   //
    dataTableGroupCompany.fnDraw();
    dataTableGroupIndustry.rowGrouping({bExpandableGrouping: true,iGroupingColumnIndex:3,iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex:4, sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "desc",fnGroupLabelFormat:function(label){ if(mapIndustry[label]!=null) return label+" ("+mapIndustry[label]+")"; else return label; }});
    dataTableGroupIndustry.fnDraw();
    dataTableGroupPeople.rowGrouping({bExpandableGrouping: true,iGroupingColumnIndex:3,iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex:4, sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "desc",fnGroupLabelFormat:function(label){ if(mapPlace[label]!=null) return label+" ("+mapPlace[label]+")"; else return label; }});
    dataTableGroupPeople.fnDraw();
    $("#sortButton").html('ASC');
    }
else
    {
    sort=true;

    dataTableGroupCompany.rowGrouping({bExpandableGrouping: true,iGroupingColumnIndex:3,iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex:4, sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "asc",fnGroupLabelFormat:function(label){ if(mapCompany[label]!=null) return label+" ("+mapCompany[label]+")"; else return label; }});
    dataTableGroupCompany.fnDraw();

    dataTableGroupIndustry.rowGrouping({bExpandableGrouping: true,iGroupingColumnIndex:3,iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex:4, sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "asc",fnGroupLabelFormat:function(label){ if(mapIndustry[label]!=null) return label+" ("+mapIndustry[label]+")"; else return label; }});
    dataTableGroupIndustry.fnDraw();

    dataTableGroupPeople.rowGrouping({bExpandableGrouping: true,iGroupingColumnIndex:3,iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex:4, sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "asc",fnGroupLabelFormat:function(label){ if(mapPlace[label]!=null) return label+" ("+mapPlace[label]+")"; else return label; }});
    dataTableGroupPeople.fnDraw();

    $("#sortButton").html('DESC');
    }

}
```

Its giving error in all rowGrouping lines just like first exception I showed here in comments. I have no idea why is this happening. The error is something like,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_aData' of undefinedjquery.dataTables.js:774 _fnGetCellDatajquery.dataTables.js:5712 fnGetDatajquery.dataTables.rowGrouping.js:415 _fnDrawCallBackWithGroupingjquery.dataTables.js:4851 _fnCallbackFirejquery.dataTables.js:1566 _fnDrawjquery.dataTables.js:2184 _fnFilterCompletejquery.dataTables.js:4099 _fnSortjquery.dataTables.js:1594 _fnReDrawjquery.dataTables.js:5558 fnDrawjquery.dataTables.rowGrouping.js:684 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:2 p.extend.eachjquery.min.js:2 p.fn.p.eachjquery.dataTables.rowGrouping.js:114 $.fn.rowGroupingpeople.html:1315 sortTogglepeople.html:1568 onclick